# Google webmaster for Adult site

Tags: google, google-search-console

I am developing an adult wallpaper website.

My question is can I use Google Webmaster Tools? Please tell me the benefit or disadvantage.

Comment: Just another filthy 18+ site... just what we need.

Answer (score 1):

It just gives you stats on crawler errors and how often google scraped your page.  It lets you give google access to sitemap files in case it cannot find them.

Not a big investment in time to setup your site to work with webmaster tools.  Its automatic now (almost) if you use google analtyics.  Otherwise you have to add a meta tag, upload a file, or add a dns record. All easy to do.

Its free, so set it up.
Chances are you wont spend too much time going over google's data on how it accesses your site.

Comment: Once a website begins getting steady traffic reviewing the data in webmaster tools is actually pretty essential to make sure Google is crawling it well and all of your pages are indexed without errors.